# Has anyone had trouble deploying Azure VM using Ubuntu 18.04 after March 8th?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, deployment

I have a template based deployment that deploys our dev, staging, and production environments.  This template has been working just fine since mid February.  When I attempted to deploy the dev site the last friday (3/9/18) the script hung with the msg:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:51:35 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'devSigmaMarketplaceUbuntuVM' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "OSProvisioningInternalError",
        "message": "OS Provisioning failed for VM 'devSigmaMarketplaceUbuntuVM' due to an internal error."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My template simply specifies that the VM should be created using 'latest' of '18.04-DAILY-LTS'

Here is a chart of what I have found that works:

```
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802180    18.04.201802180
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802190    18.04.201802190
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802210    18.04.201802210
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802220    18.04.201802220
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802230    18.04.201802230
OK - UbuntuServer      Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201802240    18.04.201802240
FAILED - UbuntuServer  Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201803070    18.04.201803070
FAILED - UbuntuServer  Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201803071    18.04.201803071
FAILED - UbuntuServer  Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201803090    18.04.201803090
FAILED - UbuntuServer  Canonical    18.04-DAILY-LTS    Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-DAILY-LTS:18.04.201803100    18.04.201803100
```

I currently have a ticket open with azure, but I am reaching out to others to se if this problem is more widespread or if its limited to my deployment.

I apologize if this is the wrong forum.  I ususally use stackexchange and i've learned to not ask non-programming questions there.

**UPDATE:**
Microsoft contacted me about the ticket regarding Ubuntu 18.04 Daily images on azure going past March 8th being 'bad'.  I was told that it is a problem with ubuntu itself, not azure.  The images sent from canonical to microsoft have problems, and I should be able to redeploy when ubuntu hits the next milestone. I have my doubts about this, but i'm willing to go along for the time being.

Added ubuntu question here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/665553

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the developers on freenode, and the bug was replicated.  This ticket is the end result.

Unable to deploy azure template with Ubuntu18.04 Daily image past March 8th
https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1755565

Overall bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1755965